# Create custom Notepad++ theme

Tags: notepad++, themes

I'm thinking of making my own Notepad++ theme for syntax coloring. I'm not sure the best way to proceed, I was hoping that someone with experience of this sort of thing could help me:

To create a new NP++ theme, is it simply a case of finding an existing theme, renaming it and then adjusting the colors in the XML? Is there an online (WYSIWYG) editor [like](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai) this but for NP++ which shows the code of your choice (JavaScript, R, C++ etc) and background colour?

Comment: Do you just want to change the colours for an existing theme or create a new theme for a new language?

Answer (score 2):

#### I'm thinking of making my own Notepad++ theme for syntax coloring.

There is an online [Notepad++ Theme Editor](https://notepad-kobzar-editor.appspot.com/editor.html):

> **About  Notepad++  Theme Editor**
>
> Created by Margaryta Tyshkevich, Olesya Yaremenko and Roman Kobzar.
>
> Link to the project code: Notepad++ Theme Editor on GitHub
>
> Implemented plugins / libraries, created by other developers :
>
> - jQuery Color Picker Plugin by Jose Vargas.
> - Downloadify JavaScript + Flash library for client side file creation by Doug Neiner.
>
> To install a theme for your Notepad++ ...
>
> - Move its XML file into your C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\themes folder.
> - Restart Notepad++ ...
> - Choose the theme from a drop-down list in Settings > Style Configurator... .

[image]

Source [About  Notepad++  Theme Editor](https://notepad-kobzar-editor.appspot.com/about.html)

Comment: I was hoping that it might include other languages other than JavaScript. It's a start thanks.

Comment: @GhoulFool Well the [source code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/m-tyshkevich/notepad-theme-editor)